# Why is CGLFlushDrawable so slow? (I am using VBOs)

Tags: opengl, buffer, flush, frame-rate

**My application details:**

Running on : Macbook pro with 4GB RAM, ATI Radeon X1600 with 128MB VRAM, Opengl version: 2.1 ATI-7.0.52

Using vertical sync (via CVDisplay) : YES

Programming Language: Lisp (Lispworks) with FFI to Opengl

**Pixel Format information**

- ns-open-gl-pfa-depth-size 32
- ns-open-gl-pfa-sample-buffers 1
- ns-open-gl-pfa-samples 6
- ns-open-gl-pfa-accelerated 1
- ns-open-gl-pfa-no-recovery 1
- ns-open-gl-pfa-backing-store 0
- ns-open-gl-pfa-virtual-screen-count 1

*[1 = YES, 0 = NO] for boolean attribs*

**I have in my application the following meshes:**

14 static meshes (which do not change). I have defined a VBO for each mesh with static draw type.

2 dynamic meshes (which change per frame). I have defined a VBO for each mesh with stream draw type.

For these dynamic meshes, per frame I do a bind buffer data with null pointer, then map buffer, update the mapped buffer and unmap the buffer.

When I run the app and check with Opengl profiler: it shows the following (Statistics View) for:

*CGLFlushDrawable:*

- Average Time (in micro sec): *52990.63 = 52.990 ms*
- % GL Time: *98.55*
- % App Time: *43.96*

No wonder I get a very poor FPS of around 6-7 FPS.

What is the way to optimize CGLFlushDrawable, since I just invoke flushBuffer which in turn invokes CGLFlushBuffer I believe.

Comment: Are you sure that some of this rendering isn't deferred, and CGLFlushDrawable is just the point at which it's finally executed, so that's where you end up seeing the cost of it?

Comment: Does using VBO imply using deferred rendering? (Being a newbie to opengl, I do not understand the concept of deferred rendering very well). From my opengl driver monitor, I saw that I have very less 'current free video memory' usually current value is around 10MB while max is around 32 MB of the total 128 MB VRAM. Could this video memory data be related to cglflushdrawable performance?

Comment: What I mean is that I've seen profilers get confused about where time is being spent in the OpenGL rendering pipeline because commands aren't executed the instant you send them. This is particularly true on the tile based deferred renderers on mobile devices, but I've also seen it on the Mac. These commands can be accumulated and finally triggered when the system needs the whole scene to be completed and presented to the screen, as happens when you use `-flushBuffer` on an NSOpenGLContext. This causes the profiler to see lots of activity on there, rather than when you sent the commands.

Comment: @Brad, thanks for the explanation. In my app event loop, I just loop through the meshes, bind VBOs etc, and finally call flushBuffer on my opengl context instance. I looked at the statistics viewer log again. I see that between CGLFlushDrawable invocations, the time spent is hardly 1 ms. But for CGLFlushDrawable, I see that some invocations take only 0.4 ms while at the other extreme it is 200ms. This seems quite odd. Or is it something thats quite normal with opengl?

Comment: Are you synchronizing your updates with the display refresh rate using a CVDisplayLink? That doesn't explain your lengthy delays, but I have seen stuttering when you're rendering out of step with the screen refreshes.

Comment: Yes, I am using CVDisplayLink. On the display link call back, I render the next scene. By synchronizing, do you mean setting the swap interval to 1?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out that ***there is a problem with my ATI Radeon X1600 graphics card***.

Without any change, when I test the same code on another newer 13" Macbook Pro which has an Intel HD Graphics 3000 with 384MB of DDR3 SDRAM, the application works fine with
around 30 FPS which is what I expect, given the dynamic meshes that I have.

Also, ***there is no bottleneck whatsoever in CGLFlushDrawable*** as was the case on my old
MBP. Further the amount of memory in VRAM available after VBO allocation remains the same
(again what I was expecting). This is not what was happening on my old MBP.

And finally, my MBP display has crashed (not regularly enough though) and external LCD display also does not work fine, which points to problems with my graphics card.

@Brad, thanks for all your inputs.